# Assign one value to multiple variables

Tags: python

I'm writing a small app for tracking work related statistics for myself. I have a class

```
class Shift():

def __init__(self):
    self.hours = None
    self.coworker = None
    ... Etc
```

What I want to do is assign all of these values as None upon the creation of a shift object. Easily done one at a time, but I was wondering if there is a way to assign None to multiple variables at once.

Comment: What you are doing right now is fine. It is easy to read and understand, and you should never sacrifice that for less amount of lines

Comment: Please clarify (to yourself as well) whether what you're trying to do is ASSIGN the same value to multiple variables, or DEFINE multiple variables that happen to be initialized to the same value. The distinction is important - Since you're using NAMED variables - and those must be EXPLICITLY defined. Had they already existed, different kinds of solutions can be used to assign values to them.

Comment: I might be going about this all wrong. What I want is to set the attributes of the shift object to none. Then at various points in the program set the various attributes to their respective values. Before storing the objects I want to be able to validate that all the attributes have been set to appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

```
self.hours = self.coworker = None
```

Or the equivalent for however many variables you have.

Comment: It is important to add here that this only works well because `None` is a singleton. Had you tried to use it for a composite type you would've gotten several variables pointing at the same object here which could've caused unexpected behavior.

Comment: It is also worth adding that this is a mess to read, even with just 2 variables it's not clear at first glance what is the intention.

Comment: @Puciek It is for anyone coming from C/C++ and the like :) But I concur that this is not very Pythonic...

Comment: @immortal I come from C++ and would never pass thing like that through code review. I have very simple rule - if at the very first glance of someone who didn't write it, it's not 100% clear what is it doing - it has to be done again.